# Using ifelse while simulating measurement error

Tags: r, simulation

I am working on a problem where I would like to have a binary variable, Z, which is a misclassified or poorly measured proxy for A, only for some level of Y.

I simulate A and Y here:

```
set.seed(76)
n=10000
#generate correctly classified treatment A
a <- (rbinom(n, 1, 0.5))    
#generate Y conditional on A
pry <- exp(-3 + 0.7*a )/(1+ exp(-1 + 0.7*a))
y <- 1*(runif(n)<=pry)
```

And then generate Z which is a misclassified version of A (in the example below, Z captures 80% of the true positives)

```
#misclassify treatment A into Z
#such that treatment is only misclassified if Y=0
ifelse(y==1, z<-a,z<-(a==1)*(runif(n)<.80))
check<-xtabs(~a+z+y)
check
```

I thought that using ifelse here would perform the A>Z misclassification only for cases where Y was zero, but looking at "check" shows this output:

```
, , y = 0

   z
a      0    1
  0 4799    0
  1  903 3821

, , y = 1

   z
a      0    1
  0  174    0
  1   54  249
```

Indicating that Z is misclassified for both Y=1 and Y=0.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the assignment inside the `ifelse()` The `ifelse()` function is a vectorized version of `if` and it evaluates it's parameters all at once. You can't do conditional assignment inside the parameters. The more common practice to to assign the result of the vectorized operation to a new variable. It would be better written as

```
z <- ifelse(y==1, a, (a==1)*(runif(n)<.80))
```